# Reinstall OS X Snow Leopard on a 2011 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, install

I have a 2011 MacBook Pro. I decided to erase all contents and reinstall the OS. I used the original installation DVD, but I could not install the OS: after the boot I could only enter Disk Utility. I verified the hard disk and it was OK. I did a hardware test and all tests pass with no error.

When I do an installation of OSX on the hard disk, the Mac hangs for hours. I hear the DVD drive spin up, and after some time it spins down again. After that the computer displays the grey apple screen only.

Because the original installation disk looked scratched I assumed that the DVD may be damaged. I ordered a new installation disk from Apple (Mac OS X Snow Leopard - with a green sticker `New version 10.6.3`). When I start up from this DVD it only displays the grey Apple screen, I can't even select an installation language or use the Disk Utility; It's as if the DVD is not bootable.

What could be wrong?
What could be my next step?

Answer (score 2):

According to this KB document:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1159

MacBook Pro (Early 2011) requires at least OS X 10.6.6, so the disc you ordered (10.6.3) does not work on your unit as it does not contain the required drivers.

Solutions:
1. You can bring your MBP to a nearby Genius Bar for reinstall, or;
2. Find a older Mac that is supported by your install disc, put your MBP into target disk mode. Run installer on that older computer and install to your target-disk-mode MBP . Once you complete software updates to 10.6.8, your MBP should be bootable again.

I suggest you get Lion so that you may use Internet recovery in the future:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4904